# Custom error page in Apache2 with https

Tags: apache, ssl, https, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to set up a custom error page for apache2 server by adding an ErrorDocument statement on the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywesite-conf-file, but I still get the default error page. The web project uses SSL.
I've tried on a local environment with a different root file (no SSL ) and the page is correctly displayed.

Is there something wrong with Apache-SSL that I don't know ??

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you tried this is the correct VirtualHost section?

Comment: Probably better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/